# Python - Pandas - Modificación parcial de cadena de caracteres contenidas en una serie

Tags: python, string, pandas

Muy buenas tardes. Mi duda es la siguiente...

Tengo este DataFrame (df):

```
      ESTACION  MAGNITUD   ANO  MES  DIA  EMISION
1812         4         1  2017    1  D01      6.0
1824         4         6  2017    1  D01      0.5
1836         4         7  2017    1  D01     55.0
1848         4         8  2017    1  D01     50.0
1860         4        12  2017    1  D01    134.0
...        ...       ...   ...  ...  ...      ...
3564        60         7  2017    1  D01     22.0
3576        60         8  2017    1  D01     58.0
3588        60        10  2017    1  D01     17.0
3600        60        12  2017    1  D01     91.0
3612        60        14  2017    1  D01     15.0

[151 rows x 6 columns]
```

Y lo que quiero es quitar la "D" a los elementos (str) de la columna "DIA". Estuve probando con "replace()" pero solo me permitía cambiar el elemento en su totalidad señalándolo de forma literal (por ahí hay algún parámetro que me permite resolver el problema). Y la idea sería resolverlo utilizando la potencia de la librería, por que había pensado en meterle un "for" pero pierde la gracia jaja. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias formas de hacer, pero todo depende del contexto, si tu campo `DIA` va a contener mas de una letra, habría problemas en usar un *slice*. Te voy a dar 2 formas de hacerlo, 1 con *slice*, 2 con expresiones regulares.

Sea cual sea la forma de hacer, tendremos que usar el metodo `apply()` del *DataFrame* de forma `df.apply()` al cual le pasaremos una `lambda` para hacer una operación en la columna

**con *slice***

```
#cogemos desde el segundo caracter hasta el final
df["DIA"] = df["DIA"].apply(lambda x: x[1:])
```

**resultado**

|  | ESTACION | MAGNITUD | ANO | MES | DIA | EMISION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 1 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 6.0 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 4 | 7 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 55.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 50.0 |
| 4 | 4 | 12 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 134.0 |

**con expresiones regulares**

```py
import re
#creamos la expresion regular
regex = re.compile(r"\d+")

df["DIA"] = df["DIA"].apply(lambda x: regex.findall(x)[0])
```

Da el mismo resultado. Una cosa que se ocurrio es que tambien lo puedes hacer usando `replace`, pues la `lambda` del método `apply()` recibe como parámetro el dato, por lo que puedes hacer esto

```py
df["DIA"] = df["DIA"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("D",""))
```

**resultado**

|  | ESTACION | MAGNITUD | ANO | MES | DIA | EMISION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 1 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 6.0 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 4 | 7 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 55.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 50.0 |
| 4 | 4 | 12 | 2017 | 1 | 01 | 134.0 |

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!! clarísimo como el agua